# php, while как понять, что цикл бежит последний раз

Tags: php, while

Как понять, что цикл бежит последний раз?

У меня есть данный PHP код

```
    if ($files['filename']['type'] != 'text/csv') {
        return array(
            'result' => false,
            'message' => 'invalid file type'
        );
    }

    $file = $files['filename']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");

    $i = 0;
    $likeStringForSelect = '';
    $likeStringForSelectToUpdate = '';
    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('default_write');
    //create sql and array data
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($i > 0) {
            $title = $quote->quote($data[38]);
            $seller_name = $quote->quote($data[69]);
            //TODO IF последний цыкл - уберать OR
            $likeStringForSelect .= ' OR item_id LIKE ' . "'" . $data[1] . "%'";
            $likeStringForSelectToUpdate .=  "(title LIKE $title AND item_id LIKE \"{$data[1]}%\" AND seller_name LIKE $seller_name ) OR ";
            //1 - item_id, 38 - title ,50 - item qty , 55 - cost , 27 - tracking number, 69 - seller name, 0 - order date
            if ($data[27] != '') $status = 'Shipped';
            else $status = 'Not shipped';

            $arrayDataFromCsv[] = array($data[1], $data[38], $data[50], $data[55], $data[27], $status, $data[0], $data[69]);
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: проверять надо не последюю итерацию, а первую

Comment: можете подробнее сказать? Использовать тогда do while?

Comment: надо проверять, если не первая итерация, то добавлять or  спереди, а если не первая, то ничего не добавлять.

Comment: Ща покажу финт. Складываем условия в массив `$likeToUpdate[] = '(...)';`. Потом вжух `implode(' OR ', $likeToUpdate);` и у нас нужная строка

Answer (score 0):

к примеру, так

```
$data =  fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",");
while ($data) {
    /*your code here*/
    $data =  fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",");
    if (!$data) {
        /*the last cycle iteration*/
    }
}
```

Comment: ответ по принципу любой говнокод, лишь бы ублажить автора вопроса

Comment: @Ипатьев давайте без оскорблений, уважаемый. Если есть конкретные замечания к ответу - изложите.